# how to SQL query to get below result:

Tags: sql

Example tables:

```
Table A   Table B
    
   A        1
   B        2
   C        3
```

Expected output:

```
A   1
A   2
A   3
B   1
B   2
B   3
C   1
C   2
C   3
```

Comment: please format you data in the proper way

Comment: Please invest a bit more effort in your question – it is pretty unclear how your data base design actually looks like as well as what the contents of are and how desired output should be derived from both.

Comment: try a `cross join`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a cross join between the two tables:

```sql
SELECT     a.column_a, b.column_b
FROM       a
CROSS JOIN b
ORDER BY   a.column_a, b.column_b
```

Comment: Interesting... Wouldn't have derived your edit from the data provided myself – but plausible ;) The answer, though, might yet contain an `ORDER BY` clause to assure the output really being the desired one...

Comment: @Aconcagua good point about the `order by` clause - edited that in. WRT the edit - I just added code fences - without them, SO doesn't render the linebreaks, so it's really impossible to make the question out.